# How can I take a values of one object and put them into another object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

Hey guys I have the following setback, I am trying to write on empty values of an object already filled another value so I can use them later, I have defined the object and I am trying to reassign the values with the new one after I receive them from API call, the problem is that the object that I am receiving is the same as the one from the API call and I don't need that, I am in need of the same structure that I have created, for this to happen I am using useState. Could you point me in the right direction?
That is my code and after it will be the result I am always getting

The initial state of deliveryAddressInput before API call

```
const [deliveryAddressInput, setDeliveryAddressInput] = useState<NewAddressDetails>({});
```

The result after the call of the API is setDeliveryAddressInput(adress):

```
BuildingName: "18A"
BuildingNumber: ""
City: "Houghton Le Spring"
Line1: "18A Nesham Place"
Line2: ""
Line3: ""
PostalCode: "DH5 8AG"
```

Initial state of the mapped object from the top one:

```
const [newAddress, setNewAddress] = useState<{}>({
    firstName: firstNameInput,
    lastName: lastNameInput,
    houseNo: deliveryAddressInput.BuildingNumber,
    houseName: deliveryAddressInput.BuildingName,
    street: deliveryAddressInput.Line1,
    addressLine2: deliveryAddressInput.Line2,
    town: deliveryAddressInput.City,
    postCode: deliveryAddressInput.PostalCode,
  });
```

The useState function:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setNewAddress(deliveryAddressInput);
    });
  }, [deliveryAddressInput]);
```

And the final result is the same as the call from the API:

```
BuildingName: "18A"
    BuildingNumber: ""
    City: "Houghton Le Spring"
    Line1: "18A Nesham Place"
    Line2: ""
    Line3: ""
    PostalCode: "DH5 8AG"
```

I am trying to receive the following which is mapping the values of the API call to the new object keys:

```
        firstName: "Jane",
        lastName: "Smith",
        houseNo: "",
        houseName: "18A",
        street: 18A Nesham Place,
        addressLine2: "",
        town: "Houghton Le Spring",
        postCode: "DH5 8AG",
```

Comment: Print the result of your API call to the console. What do you see?

Comment: As you can see there is a example after the Call of the API

Comment: OK I see. Where from you get firstName / lastName and so on?

Comment: Only those two properties are coming from an another input with their respecting useState

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should convert one object into another:

```
    const convertDeliveryInputIntoAddress = (
      deliveryAddressInput, firstName, lastName
      ) => {
        const {BuildingName, BuildingNumber, City, Line1, PostalCode} = deliveryAddressInput;
        const firstLineSplitted = Line1.split(' ');
        const houseName = firstLineSplitted[0];
        const street = firstLineSplitted.slice(1).join(' ');
        return {firstName, lastName, houseNo: buildingNumber, houseName, street, town: City, postCode: PostalCode};
      }

    ...
    setNewAddress(convertDeliveryInputIntoAddress(deliveryAddressInput, firstName, lastName));
```